# Why is energy maximized in an air gap?

Tags: electromagnetic

[image]

Suppose we have an air gap problem like in the picture above. Now the induced MMF will clearly move the object in the negative x direction. It will do this because energy is maximized. Due to coenergy also being maximized so is inductance. This happens because relucantce is minimized.

I'm avoiding using equations here right now and I am trying to understand the mathematics I already know.

Now conceptually a system will always seek minimum energy for stability and the equilibrium points of even a simple system like this WILL occur at points of minimum energy.

However the air gap seems to defy stability. It is intrinsicly unstable because it if it were not for that block in the way the object would shoot off in the -x direction.

WHY does an air gap system seek to maximize its energy and inductance and minimize its reluctance? What's the real electromagnetic phenomenon occuring here?

I have a thought we can maybe build on:

My thought is that as the gap widens and the reluctance of the system decreases, the inductance increases and much like a two wires splitting this splitting will cause the EMF. Is a similar situation occuring here with the MMF? and why?

Comment: If the gap widens, the reluctance _increases_, not decreases.

Comment: You are confused on several points.  The primary one is that *any* system will tend to move to *minimize* the energy.  Rocks fall *down*, not *up*.  Capacitors *discharge*, etc.  You may be confusing energy with coenergy -- if so, remember that coenergy is just a convenient fiction that makes the arithmetic easier; the underlying reality is that you're computing what happens to the energy itself.

Comment: I don't know the reasoning(I suspect this is simply something about the universe that we have been able to measure and test without knowing the cause), but the natural lowest possibility state for a line of magnetic flux is the state in which it has the shortest possible path(Ignoring the fact that flux in reality is probably not a set of discrete lines), and for a system the lowest energy state is that in which the greatest number of flux lines have the shortest possible path.  Passing though a lower permeability area tends to limit the total number of flux lines, with a larger area limiting

Comment: less than a smaller one.  Given these two properties of the universe and looking at the diagram you show, it is clear that the solenoid core must move to the left, as that removes the airgap of low cross section and maximizes the airgap with large cross section.  This must happen because the lowest energy state requires that the largest possible number of flux lines have the shortest possible path, and having an air gap of larger cross section accommodates more flux lines.  Carrying this to inductance, it appears to me that as soon as the center moves left, it provides a "better" core

Comment: and therefore greater inductance due to the higher average permeability of the circuit.

Comment: As far as stability, I don't believe the system is intrinsically unstable.  If the parts of the object being evaluated that stop the center travelling in the -x direction were not present, we would be evaluating a different object and a different system, so anything we could say about what would happen if part of the object wasn't there is irrelevant to the question at hand.  I think "Stability" of the system would have to do with its ability to maintain a predictable state with a given set of parameters.  As drawn, it has no spring to return it to original state.

Comment: Magnetic systems like that have a force/displacement characteristic that goes \$F = k\frac{1}{x}\$.  Without external devices to lend stability, this leads to real honest-to-gosh instability in the bounded-input, unbounded-output sense (or, unbounded until it smacks into a bit of itself).